# Integrate linphone into iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, linphone

I am trying to add linphone lib to my existing iOS app, but it fails to build

My process:

1. Added all the required frame works in my existing project.
2. Copied all lib from linphone-iphone/liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/lib/   to myproject/lib
3. Copied  linphone-iphone/Resources to myproject/Resources
4. Then I added  LinphoneManager.h & .m  with there related files.
5. Then I started build the app, I am getting  file not found  #include "ortp/ortp.h" in Linphonecore (but file is available).

What I understand from the error is, I need to modify the build setting to search the file. I have done that but I still get the same error.

Comment: In linphone project ,How to add the "include" folder to my project.

Answer (score 0):

See the **Header Search Paths** in your Build Settings.
And copy paste them from the Linphone sample app.[image]

Comment: Errors about including ortp/ortp.h ?

Comment: Which one? I did implement Linphone into my project but interested in another libraries for SIP

Comment: artyom Could you please tell me, what i need to do to implement linphone in one of my iOS app.

Comment: Download linphone from their repository. Follow README file instructions. After you compile the source files, you should look at linphone sample project configuration and reproduce all these configurations in your project. After that you should be abel to build project

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081140/integrate-linphone-app-to-my-ios-app/31458185#31458185). It's a bit long but I sincerely hope it is clear enough and will help you (and the others in the future) to build and integrate Linphone!

Best,

Answer (score 0):

For "ortp/ortp.h" File Not Found Error!

1. Check your "linphone-sdk" fold, if added to the project
2. If added, check the libOrtp.a in linphone-sdk/apple-darwin/lib/
3. If exist, check the "Build Phases" -> "link binary with libraries", if "libOrtp.a" included
4. After all above are done, check the "Build settings" -> "header search paths", and add "$(SRCROOT)/liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/include"

Problem solved!