# Linphone for iOS

Tags: ios, compilation, linphone

I need to build linphone for iOS (and android and windows after that, but that is of later concern). Since no one is able to answer [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763472/linphone-compiling-problems-on-osx) nor [a similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739270/integrate-linphone-into-ios), can someone at least point me to a good resource on the subject? I feel like I tried everything already, and the project still won't compile (lot's of files missing, include paths are wrong, libraries can't be found etc...). Linphone doesn't have a forum as far as I know, and any threads I find on the internet are unanswered. SO has 14 questions about linphone in total uncluding this one, 3 of which are answered.

Want I want is to compile linphone for iOS, what I need for that is a good lead on how to set everything up. This is what I have tried:
-Every step in README.macos (turned out to be the wrong project, I needed the iphone one)
-Every step in linphone-iphone/README (I have an xcode project now)
-Opened the xcode project and tried to compile (lots of missing files)
-Tried fixing include paths in the source and adding the missing libs manually (Ran into files referencing non-existent files)

I also tried [this guide](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/linphone-developers/2011-08/msg00024.html) and [this one](http://shallwelearn.com/blog/?p=6). Both are pretty much the same as what is described in the readme files, with some minor differences, so I tried them anyway.

I'm missing various .a files (I have a project folder for most, but compiling them doesn't result in the lib being installed). I also miss some .h files, even some that are supposed to be in the same folder as some I do have. And I missed one .png file (linphone-banner.png) which I downloaded and put in the right folder already.

Comment: @user366584 I have followed [this guide](http://shallwelearn.com/blog/?p=6) now, with all permissions to read/write for everyone, and it worked. Apparently I had permission problems, which got fixed that way. Also, you should get the latest git version, because there was a bug in the previous one that made the app crash on video calls. So to make it work, follow the guide, and make sure you have sufficient permissions on your entire 'linphone-iphone' folder. I hope this can help you, as it did for me.

Comment: Please refer to my answer

[Good Blog][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609763/how-to-integrate-linphone-into-an-existing-project-sip-in-ios/15925914#15925914

Comment: follow this , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085667/integrate-linphone-for-iphone/56691850#56691850

Comment: @Chathuranga Thanks! The question is over 6 years old though, I don't really work with Linphone anymore. but I'll give you an upvote on the answer just for your dedication to knowledge sharing ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have followed [this guide](http://shallwelearn.com/blog/build-linphone-for-iphone-and-ipad/) now, with all permissions to read/write for everyone, and it worked. Apparently I had permission problems, which got fixed that way. Also, you should get the latest git version, because there was a bug in the previous one that made the app crash on video calls. So to make it work, follow the guide, and make sure you have sufficient permissions on your entire 'linphone-iphone' folder. I hope this can help you, as it did for me.

Comment: The link you attached is dead !

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081140/integrate-linphone-app-to-my-ios-app/31458185#31458185). It's a bit long but I sincerely hope it is clear enough and will help you (and the others in the future) to build and integrate Linphone!

Best,