# Integrate Linphone for iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, linphone, xcode6.4

I want to implement Linphone into my project but i'm stuck in between and I don't know where to go now.

What I've done is downloaded linphone-iphone-master sdk
[masterhttps://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone)

and then this liblinphone-sdk from gtihub and included lib, include folder to it. After compiling it give me this error.

```
liblinphone SDK not found. Please refer to the README: you have to compile liblinphone SDK before building Linphone application.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I'm also a new to this and searched lot of things but couldn't find anything and don't know what to do please help me.

I also installed home brew as it shows and there's [this](http://shallwelearn.com/blog/build-linphone-for-iphone-and-ipad/)
website which i'm following but getting no success.

Answer (score 1):

**If you don't want build linphone-sdk by yourself, you can directly download it from linphone website**, http://www.linphone.org/releases/ios/liblinphone-iphone-sdk-latest.zip.

After downloading it (will be a zip file - " liblinphone-iphone-sdk-latest.zip"), unzip it (will unzip to "liblinphone-sdk" folder).

Just copy paste "liblinphone-sdk" folder into your linphone-iphone project folder.

You're done! Run linphone-iphone xcode project. Now, it should build and run without any error.

**Note:** *Building/rebuilding linphone-sdk manually is required if you want to make any change in pre-builded linphone-sdk, http://www.linphone.org/releases/ios/liblinphone-iphone-sdk-latest.zip.*

Comment: Thanks @Nitesh Borad for your time, I had success in building linphone sdk manually.

Comment: Please let me know @Nitesh if you know where are login and signup api for integration beacause I could not able to find it.

Comment: @Nij: There are FirstLoginViewController.h/.m files in "~/linphone-iphone/Classes". Which are written for login functionality.

For login, modify "- (void)startUp" method in "~/linphone-iphone/Classes/PhoneMainView.m".

My sample code is:

- (void)startUp {
        //add your code to check userLoggedIn
        if(userLoggedIn){
            [self changeCurrentView: [DialerViewController compositeViewDescription]];
        }
        else {
            // Change to fist login view
            [self changeCurrentView: [FirstLoginViewController compositeViewDescription]];
        }
    }

Comment: i'm talking about their web services used to login in linphone, what I need is to call my web services which are in php and then want to pass that login credenstials to their web services.

Comment: I had success in building local Linphone SDK for iOS, but struggling to specify iOS version, default is `iOS 9.0`

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to build your own SDK you should go for this [link](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone) and do the readme file steps. Otherwise if want to compile the code using your local SDK you should follow this steps.

Before you build SDK first install all these tool on your mac.

1. cmake >= 3.6

   - python = 2.7 (python 3.7 if C# wrapper generation is disabled)
   - pip
   - yasm
   - nasm
   - doxygen
   - Pystache (use `pip install pystache`)
   - six (use `pip install six`)

For this I recommended first install python 3 on your mac. it'll save you from lot of issues when you are installing last two steps. And download using this git command,

git clone https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-sdk.git --recursive

After that go to downloaded folder and make folder called "build". then go inside that folder and do these steps to build your local SDK,

1. Execute CMake to configure the project:
   `cmake ..`
2. Build the SDK:
   `cmake --build .` 
   or 
   `cmake --build . --parallel <number of jobs>` (which is faster).

You can pass some options to CMake at the second step to configure the SDK as you want.
For instance, to build an iOS SDK (the default being Desktop):
 `cmake .. -DLINPHONESDK_PLATFORM=IOS`

If you want to use any other features with your local SDK please refer the readme file in your downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

As it says, before building via Xcode you need to build the SDK. You need to use Terminal to cd to the linphone-iphone directory and use the `./prepare.py && make` command.

Comment: Yes, I did that but it gives me this error
ERROR:root:Could not find prepare module: 'module' object has no attribute 'Target', probably missing submodules/cmake-builder? Try running:
git submodule update --init --recursive

Comment: Have you run `git submodule update --init --recursive` and then run `./prepare.py && make` again?

Comment: Do i've have to use terminal for that also?
I tried using that git submodule update --init --recursive but no success. Also I have downloaded directly from github.

Comment: Doing git for that command gives me another error.
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: Sorry for this but i've no idea how to use git command line tool in mac, I already have git command line tool package installed.

Comment: Delete the old directory, then run this on command line: `git clone git@github.com:BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone`

Comment: It's a long process and still going on will update you after that and thanks for the help :)

Comment: Have done all the process and completely cloned after that i'm doing ./prepare.py && make which gives me this: `The following binaries are missing: nasm. Please install them using:
 brew install nasm`  `Warning: nasm-2.11.08_1 already installed`

Comment: After that try running `./prepare.py && make` again.

Comment: Still facing the same issue saying nasm binary is not installed and this thing is now headache to me please help me anyway sir.

Comment: Hmmm. It is very strange that it would say that it is installed, then say it isn't.

Comment: I'm entering `./prepare.py && make` for linphone and terminal says `ERROR: The following binaries are missing: nasm. Please install them using:
 brew install nasm`

I then tried `brew install nasm` and it gives warning that `nasm-2.11.08_1 already installed` also did reinstalling the brew but it isn't working.

Comment: Hi @ThomasW, finally i'm got success in compiling and running linphone for iphone. What wrong i've done was, I was using nasm Apple one which is obsolete so used brew version and did the following trick and it worked for me.Something like: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` and got something like this 

`$ nasm -v
NASM version 2.11.08 compiled on Nov 26 2015
$ which nasm
/usr/local/bin/nasm`

Now the question is what i've to do further to create my own app like linphone. Should I change their storyboard or what please help me in this.