# Integrate Linphone app to my iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sip, linphone

There are about 20 questions on Linphone ios build in StackOverflow. A couple of them ask about integrating Linphone to an existing xcode project. I have followed them all. I am able to build and run the Linphone project successfully.

However, to integrate to my existing project, I have included:

- **linphone-sdk/apple-darwin/include** and **linphone-sdk/apple-darwin/lib** to my project.
- the following lines to **Xcode project->Build Settings->Search Path/Header Search Path**: submodules/linphone/coreapi submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/include
  submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/include submodules/linphone/oRTP/include submodules/externals/gsm/ submodules/externals/osip/include submodules/externals/exosip/include submodules/externals/speex/include Classes/Utils/NinePatch/ Classes/Utils/XMLRPC/
- marking **all .a with target membership to my current target**

What else should i do to get Linphone working in my project? Or should I **make a static library of Linphone**? If Yes, what things should i take care about?

Comment: Did you successfully integrate the SDK with your app?? if so please tell me how cause i'm stuck at it !!!

Comment: im also getting ortp/ortp.h not found. aplease tell me any solution.

Answer (score 9):

To be able to build and run Linphone on a Swift project I had to the following steps:

1. **Downlaod the latest SDK (with wget) from:**
   http://www.linphone.org/snapshots/ios/liblinphone-iphone-sdk-latest.zip
2. **Copy,paste and insert in the project:**

   - liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/include
   - liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/lib
   - liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/share/images
   - liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/share/sounds
3. **Create a Bridging-Header.h with:**

   - `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`
   - `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`
   - `#import <linphone/linphonecore.h>`
4. **Create a PrefixHeader.pch which import your Bridging-Header:**

   - `#import "Bridging-Header.h"`
5. **Integrate The following pods:**

   - `pod 'xmlrpc', '~> 2.3.4'`
   - `pod 'Tortuga22-NinePatch', '~> 0.1.1'`
6. **Configure the build Settings:**

`

```
GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER = YES
GCC_PREFIX_HEADER = path/to/PrefixHeader.pch
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC $(inherited)
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited)
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) ${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public $(PROJECT_DIR)/External/liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/include
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)/External/liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/lib $(PROJECT_DIR)/External/liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/lib/mediastreamer/plugins
```

`

7. **Configure the macros:**

`

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) HAVE_OPENH264 HAVE_SILK HAVE_SSL
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = $(inherited) -D HAVE_OPENH264 -D HAVE_SILK -D HAVE_SSL
```

`

8. **Libraries and Framework:**

First add all the libs from the folder (and subfolders) `liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/lib`.
Then be sure to add the following list:

*Pods:*

- libPods.a

*Dynamic Libs:*

- libz.dylib
- libiconv.dylib
- libxml2.dylib
- libsqlite3.dylib
- libc++.dylib
- libstdc++.6.dylib
- libresolv.dylib

*Frameworks:* (sorry I'm not sure if they are all 100% needed but this is how I managed to get the lib to build)

- AudioToolbox.framework
- UIKit.framework
- QuartzCore.framework
- OpenGLES.framework
- MessageUI.framework
- MediaPlayer.framework
- CoreGraphics.framework
- MobileCoreServices.framework
- AddressBookUI.framework
- AddressBook.framework
- SystemConfiguration.framework
- CFNetwork.framework
- AssetsLibrary.framework
- AVFoundation.framework
- CoreAudio.framework
- CoreMedia.framework
- CoreTelephony.framework
- CoreVideo.framework
- Foundation.framework
- CoreLocation.framework

*How to test:*

To verify that it was working, I integrated some sample code from the Linphone app and made some minor setups in my view controllers.
To do so I integrated in the project the following classes:

- Utils.[h, m]
- LinphoneManager.[h, m]
- LinphoneCoreSettingsStore.[h, m]
- FastAddressBook.[h, m]
- LinphoneIOSVersion.h
- pod 'InAppSettingsKit', '~> 2.6'

PS: I had to update them in order to build without warnings or errors.

I hope this will help someone one day!

Comment: Hey, Kevin, thanks for the instructions! I'm close to getting it to work. But I still get many errors in `LinphoneManager.h`. I'm not sure what would be safe to delete. Could you share your working project? Or at least the Linphone files modified in order to work with a Swift Project?

Comment: @Kevin I am trying to use it but getting the following error. can you help me out.
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_libmsamr_init", referenced from: -[LinphoneManager createLinphoneCore] in LinphoneManager.o "

Answer (score 1):

Check with below Header Search Paths. Also set **Other Linker Flags** `-ObjC`

[image]

Comment: I have already mentioned this above. Anything else to be done?