# Configure LinePhone in Xcode9.3.1

Tags: swift, xcode, github, linphone-sdk

How to configure LinePhone SDK in Xcode9.3.1 ?

I was try following links :

http://shallwelearn.com/blog/build-linphone-for-iphone-and-ipad/

https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone

https://medium.com/@yagnik.suthar/build-linphone-easily-in-ios-for-all-any-versions-b6175ec90e9e

[Integrate Linphone app to my iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081140/integrate-linphone-app-to-my-ios-app)

Comment: Are you able to successfully integrated linphone sdk with Swift project?

Comment: Yes I did in my project. And I mentation all steps in below answer. Please follow its

Answer (score 2):

I was try multiple documents to configure LinePhone Sdk in Xcode9.3.1 and Final I was Done. Here I share Step by Step How to configure LinePhone SDK.

**1. Install iTerm2 app in your System.**

- here is Link : https://www.iterm2.com
- Its same as Terminal

**2. Install Homebrew**

- Open iTerm App
- copy and paste this link : /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
- more information follow : https://brew.sh

**3. Create a NewFolder(Like:Demo, Where you want to configure project)**

- Go into Demo folder through iTerm.( ***:~ ***$ cd /Users/jiniguruios/Desktop/Demo)

**4. Start Configure LinePhone**

- git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-iphone.git --recursive
- wait till it's not complete.
- After completed there was **Demo/linphone-iphone** Folder you can see.
- Then : cd Demo/linphone-iphone
- ./prepare.py (if you got any error try this: "git submodule update --recursive --init" brfore "./prepare.py"
- wait till completed after
- export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
- ./prepare.py -c && ./prepare.py && make
- ./prepare.py [options] && make (There is multiple option as per your requirements , I was take : *./prepare.py arm64 && make*)
- 4 architectures currently exists on iOS:
- 64 bits ARM64 for iPhone 5s, iPad Air, iPad mini 2, iPhone 6, iPhone 6 Plus, iPad Air 2, iPad mini 3.
- 32 bits ARMv7 for older devices.
- 64 bits x86_64 for simulator for all ARM64 devices.
- 64 bits x86_64 for simulator for all ARM64 devices.

  **Wait till Complete all process**

After the SDK has been built, add all the .framework files located in liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/Frameworks to your XCode project Embedded Frameworks and linked binaries. Make sure that your project FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS contains "$(PROJECT_DIR)/liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/Frameworks" Make sure that your project HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS contains "$(SRCROOT)/liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/include" Make sure that your project LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS contains "$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks"; Add a Run Script step to your build steps, put it after your step to embed frameworks, set it to use our deploy.sh script located in the Tools folder of linphone-iphone root directory.